# How to combine two tables so the new one to have only new records from the first and all the rest from the second?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table A with 1 million records and a table B with 10 million records. Table A can have new records not present in table B. How I can combine the two tables so the table C to have all the records from A and all the records from B but with updated records from A. Both tables A and B have a column ID  by which both can be joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run a query and follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result).

I would construct the query using the [Join clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). For example:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Find a detailed explanation for the different types of Joins in BigQuery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types).